How to save transparent fire in blender
I'm trying to save a render of a fire flame in Blender I have followed the steps of this tutorial, but I'm having empty png's and tiff files, please help me solve this problem. I'm using Bleder 4.2.3 LTS on a MacOS Ventura my GPU is Intel hd 630 and AMD Radeon Pro 560
here are screenshots:

this is the view layer with the color-activated it shows the fire mask

this is the fire colors node setup with volume BSDF

this is the compositor node setup
